# How to find article text size is changed in Android app

Tags: java, android, selenium, android-uiautomator

I am writing automation for Andriod App.

Steps:-

1. Go to app homepage
2. I will open an first article
3. How do i find an text size of an article.

I will set article content size in App.

When i set article content size as Small/Medium/Large.
How do i verify content size in article page?

Article Page:-
[image]

Article Content type Selection:-

[image]

Comment: by default size of textview is 10 dp hight

Comment: it depends inside of small ,medium and large look inside logic what the size have declared...

Answer (score 0):

You have to use textview.getTextSize(); 
It will return value in float